# Do I have to unlink a fifo before I can read from it?

Tags: java, c, fifo

I'm using a c process to listen to a serial port and sending it to a java program to do processing on the data.

I run the c program, which makes a call to `mkfifo()`, it blocks, waiting for the java program to open the other end.

Once the java program opens the other end, the c program enters a loop, reading from the serial port and calling `write(fd)` with the file descriptor.

The java program doesn't get the data until I kill the C process, or the c process makes a call to `unlink()`.

Is this the only way to pass data? Do I have to use a message queue if I want to keep it open?

From my research, it appears that `write` is not buffered, so I don't have to do anything like `fflush` for if I was using a file pointer, but then why isn't it sending?

Comment: If the C program is writing to the FIFO with `write()`, then the data should be there ready for the Java program to read, and the issue is "what is the Java program doing"?  You can demonstrate this by using a C program to read the FIFO instead of the Java; run `cat /path/to/FIFO` to read it, for example.  You should not need to unlink the FIFO.  You might need to reopen it.  If you're reading and there are no writers left, you need to close and reopen before you'll get more data.  There might be a similar issue if you're writing.

Comment: You're right, cat works so it's likely the java end. I'll take a look at it when I get a chance and see what's going on there

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using `bufferedreader.readLine()`, instead of just `read`. Changing to read with a buffer fixed it

Answer (score -1):

have you tied to set the O_ASYNC flag on the read end?